# Why a R function containing approx. 400 lines of code has 633Kb?

Tags: r, function

I'm writing an R script that has a function containing about 400 lines of code. It was assigned as a "Large function", of size 633 Kb. A text editor saves it as 40K.
Why is it so larger in R?

Comment: functions have associated *environments* which may store additional data ...

Comment: Your file might not only contain the code but also the data. I'd suggest loading your data programmatically from the script. If it's still that big, break it up, and source the different parts.